# grails mail not working

Tags: email, grails

grails project. i use email plugin and getting an exception when try call method 'sendMail'

error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: Unable to locate provider for protocol: smtp. Failed messages: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: Unable to locate provider for protocol: smtp; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: Unable to locate provider for protocol: smtp
```

config.groovy

```
grails {
    mail {
        host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        port = 465
        username = "mymail@gmail.com"
        password = "mypass"
        props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
                //"mail.smtp.port":"465",
                //"mail.debug":"true",
                "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
                "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
                "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
    }
}
```

example of sending

```
sendMail {
                    to "fred@gmail.com"
                    subject "Hello Fred"
                    body 'How are you?'
                }
```

what am I doing wrong?

[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406564/using-java-to-send-emails-on-gmail-account)

Answer (score 1):

The error say `Unable to locate provider for protocol: smtp`. It seems you're missing some dependencies for the smtp protocol, which seems very odd, apparently you're missing javamail (?). Because the code seems good to me.

Comment: grails user library contains "geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove

```
            "mail.smtp.port":"465",
            "mail.debug":"true",
```

from your config? This is the only difference I see between your code and the official example.

Update: as GalmWing already stated, it seems to be a problem with your java.mail jar file. Please check this solution: [Using Java to send emails on gmail account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406564/using-java-to-send-emails-on-gmail-account) . It sounds to me like you have the same problem. Which java-version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

add to config.groovy

```
grails {
    mail {
      host = "smtp.gmail.com"
      port = 465
      username = "email"
      password = "pwd"
      props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
               "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
               "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
               "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
    }
 }
```

use this code to send mails

```
def sendEmail(){

    mailService.sendMail {
        to "email","**email**"
        from "email"
        subject "Hi"
        body 'Hi'
    }
}
```

also dont forget to inject mailservice in your class

```
def mailService
```

this will inject the service to your class

and this configuration will be sufficient to send mails