# Java mail don't return subject

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, tomcat6

I'm using javamail to rescue mails of inbox. I get all mails from inbox, but the subject(message.getSubject()) return null.

I research in several sites and all proposed solutions not work.

This problem occurs only in the Tomcat6, if a execute even code in java project for main method i get all atributis, include subject. I'm user de SSL protocol (pop3s).

Thanks for help

```
public void getMails(final String host, final int port, final String user, final String password){

   final Session session = Session.getInstance(System.getProperties(), null);
   final Store store = session.getStore("pop3s");   

   store.connect(host, port, user, password);
   Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
   inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
   int count = inbox.getMessageCount();
   System.out.println(" Count Emails "+count);

   final Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();                
   for (final Message message : messages) { 
       //This return null
       System.out.print("mail subject: " + message.getSubject() + " send at: " + message.getSentDate());
       //This return body of mail
       System.out.print("mail subject: " + message.getContent().toString());
}
```

> My output for the method Main directly on eclipse:

**MessageCount:** 4

**full name:** INBOX

**NewMessageCount:** 0

**getDescription:** null

**getFileName:** null

**getMessageNumber:** 1

**getSize:** 2297

**getSentDate:** Mon Aug 03 17:23:10 BRT 2015

**from:** Silvano Wojczak silvano.wojczak@softexpertjlle.onmicrosoft.com

**Content:** javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@6769ba97

**Content getClass:** class javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart

> For log4j in TomCat6:

**MessageCount:** 4

**full name:** INBOX

**NewMessageCount:** 0

**getDescription:** null

**getFileName:** null

**getMessageNumber:** 1

**getSize:** 6731

**getSentDate:** null

**from:** null

**Content:** javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@6769ba97

**Content getClass:** class javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using?  Make sure your Tomcat installation doesn't have a different version of JavaMail installed.  Turn on [JavaMail session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug); the debug output will tell you what version you're using, and may provide clues as to what's going wrong.

Comment: @BillShannon I am using **mail-1.4.7**. I read on some sites that might be a problem with the **axis.jar** libs and her incompatibility with javamail the tomcat6. I realized some mentioned procedures to solve the problem more incompatilidade not resolve.

Comment: That's an old version of JavaMail, but I don't think that's the source of your problems.  You're using that same version with all of your programs, right?  If you call message.getContent() before message.getSubject(), does it make a difference?  Are you sure your POP3 server is properly implementing the TOP command?  Although that wouldn't explain why your program only fails on Tomcat.  When message.getSubject() fails, does message.getSentDate() and message.getFrom() also fail?  Or does only message.getSubject() fail?  You may need to post the whole debug output for us to see what's wrong.

Comment: @BillShannon I updated the question with the output data, see above

Comment: It is great that your question was solved, but please don't edit your question title to show that. Either accept the posted answer if it helped your, or post your own answer to explain what you did to solve your problem.

Comment: @Tom sorry for this, i accept the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the runtime of your installation of Tomcat 6 has its own implementation of JavaMail.

You'd better ensure first which implementation of JavaMail are you using *actually*. Execute this scrap in the same program that reads the mail, immediately before the error occurs:

```
    String packageName="javax.mail.internet.";
    String simpleClassName="MimeMultipart";
    String className=packageName+simpleClassName;
    Class<?> cl=Class.forName(className);
    URL url=cl.getResource(simpleClassName+".class");
    System.out.println("url="+url);
```

Once I suffered this kind of problems when using older implementations of `geronimo-mail`, and I got to solved them by *cloning* the message before reading the headers:

```
private static MimeMessage cloneMimeMessage(Session session, MimeMessage src)
    throws MessagingException
{
    if (src instanceof POP3Message)
    {
        return new MimeMessage(session, ((POP3Message)src).top(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    }
    else if (src instanceof IMAPMessage)
    {
        return new MimeMessage(session, ((IMAPMessage)src).getRawInputStream());
    }
    else
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: He returned this   `url=jar:file:/C:/Desenvolvimentos/sesuite/1.3/platform/webapps/softexpert/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar!/javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.class`, i'll try to update this lib. In another question suggested deleting this lib, could this be? [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406564/using-java-to-send-emails-on-gmail-account()

Comment: SURE! As I commented before, I had troubles myself with those geronimo-javamail implementations when parsing mail messages. The second option is, as I said, _cloning_ the message just after recovered from the mailbox.

Comment: I'ts Work. The solution is: I deleted the lib **geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1** of my project and now my project is using this **mail lib-1.4.2.jar**. As shown in url: `url=jar:file:/C:/Desenvolvimentos/sesuite/1.3/platform/webapps/softexpert/WEB-INF/lib/mail-1.4.2.jar!/javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.class`. Thanks for help!

Comment: In our case, we this is yielding test failures on our CI and cleaning up the ivy cache wouldn't help because someone else would place geronimo javamail again. How can we be sure do not use the implementation? We tried to force the mail.pop3.class to com.sun.mail.store.POP3SSLStore but the getSubject returns null and our test fails

Comment: I suppose you should set Geronimo Javamail as an **exclusion** in your `ivy.xml` file.