# No such method com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.json.WatchersJsonParserBuilder.createWatchersParser

Tags: java, json, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I am working on an application in which I am trying to integrate JIRA functionality. When I try to run the code for creating a task, I get an error. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help would be nice.

Also, how can I create a project in the locally running JIRA instance. I cannot see the option in dashboard. Any help would be nice.

Error log :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.json.WatchersJsonParserBuilder.createWatchersParser()Lcom/atlassian/jira/rest/client/internal/json/JsonObjectParser;
    com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousIssueRestClient.<init>(AsynchronousIssueRestClient.java:69)
    com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClient.<init>(AsynchronousJiraRestClient.java:48)
    com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.create(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:37)
    com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:42)
    com.journaldev.spring.JIRA.CreateMinimalTask.doTask(CreateMinimalTask.java:31)
```

Code :

```
// Also, what are the keys below, and where can I find documentation about it. 
 private static final String PROJECT_KEY = "TST";
    private static final long TASK_TYPE_ID = 3L;
    private static final long SUBTASK_TYPE_ID = 5L;
    private static final String SUMMARY = "summary";

    public void doTask() throws IOException {

        final JiraRestClient restClient = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory().createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(
                serverUri, username, password);

        final IssueInputBuilder parentBuilder = new IssueInputBuilder(PROJECT_KEY, TASK_TYPE_ID, "parent");
        final IssueInput parentInput = parentBuilder.build();

        try {

            final IssueRestClient client = restClient.getIssueClient();
            final BasicIssue parent = client.createIssue(parentInput).claim();
            System.out.println("parent: " + parent);


            final IssueInputBuilder childBuilder = new IssueInputBuilder(PROJECT_KEY, SUBTASK_TYPE_ID, "child");
            childBuilder.setFieldValue("parent", ComplexIssueInputFieldValue.with("key", parent.getKey()));
            final BasicIssue child = client.createIssue(childBuilder.build()).claim();

            final Issue actual = client.getIssue(parent.getKey()).claim();

            for (final Subtask subtask : actual.getSubtasks()) {
                final Issue actualChild = client.getIssue(subtask.getIssueKey()).claim();
                final JSONObject json = (JSONObject) actualChild.getField("parent").getValue();
            }

            client.deleteIssue(parent.getKey(), true).claim();
        } finally {
            if (restClient != null) {
                restClient.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Any help would be nice as I am new to JIRA.

Comment: Generally speaking, a `NoSuchMethodError` is caused by having different libraries in the execution environment than in the compilation one. Check the libraries (and versions) of the production envirnoment against those you used for compiling.

Comment: @LittleSanti : That's quite a broad stroke as I am copying the libraries required from JIRA site itself. WHich ones if you could mention might give this problem would be nice.

Comment: You have to find it yourself: Look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31794998/java-mail-dont-return-subject/31809135#31809135 about how to trace which library belongs a certain class to.